# I hope that is helpful

Tags: expressions

In a textbook published by Oxford University Press, there is an email written by a booking manager in reply to a customer's request for a discount:

> Dear __________ ,
>
> We would be able to offer you a 10 % discount on the total. I hope that is helpful.
>
> Regards,

What is another way to say the second sentence? Is it OK to say "I hope you're satisfied" or "I hope this could meet your expectation"? I thought it's kind of awkward to say "I hope you're satisfied" since the customer hadn't received any benefit when the letter was written.

Could any of you help? Thanks for your reply in advance!

Comment: "***We*** *hope this meets your satisfaction*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I hope you are satisfied" would likely be a very poor choice of words, as this statement is a common colloquial invective, with the implied meaning of "you have injured me greatly, I am angry, and want you to be sorry for what you did".  This would be a good opportunity to use the passive tense.  "I hope this will be satisfactory." lacks the negative connotations of the previous phrase, and takes the focus off a person's opinions (which can be an argumentative and personal subject) and puts it onto the quality of the offer instead.

"I hope this could meet your expectation" is also a little strange, mostly due to the past tense nature of "could", and the fact that "expectation" is usually pluralized.  Try "I hope this will meet your expectations."

Comment: I think in the context of a business dealing such as that provided by the OP,  *I hope you're satisfied* will hardly carry such sharp association like those you mentioned above. All *I hope you're satisfied* does is that it carries connotations of cessation of a conversation, leaving no door open to further negotiations. Your alternate suggestions are good though.

Comment: I think the sharp connotations with "I hope you're satisfied" are sufficiently ingrained into the language that it would be felt, at least a little, even in a business context.  Even if it doesn't have the full weight, there'd still be a feeling of abruptness, and perhaps a bit of anger.  Safer to avoid the pitfall altogether.

Comment: I really appreciate the answers from both of you! Your replies help me a lot in understanding the subtle differences between these expressions.